# Running Raku notebook in Docker

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, raku

Running [Raku (previously aka Perl 6) kernel](https://github.com/bduggan/p6-jupyter-kernel) in Jupyter notebook would be great for reproducibility and ease of use (personal view).

I wanted to run the [Perl 6 notebook](https://github.com/bduggan/p6-jupyter-kernel) in a docker container and access it in my web browser. For this I [created this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sumankhanal/raku-notebook/).

The code to create the docker image was:

```
FROM sumankhanal/rakudo:2019.07.1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ca-certificates python3-pip && pip3 install jupyter notebook \
    && zef install Jupyter::Kernel --force-test

ENV TINI_VERSION v0.6.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /usr/bin/tini
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "--"]

EXPOSE 8888
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0"]
```

I am on `Windows 10 64 bit` and IP address of my docker is `192.168.99.100`.

When I tried to run the container with this code:

`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 sumankhanal/raku-notebook` in the docker terminal

I get this error:

```
$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 sumankhanal/raku-notebook
[I 14:26:43.598 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1296, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1120, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 142, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 197, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Any help ?

Comment: I ran your image on my VM and it ran fine, except the only thing it needed was `--allow-root` in the `CMD`. Can you restart your Docker and then try again? Also update the CMD. It works but i don't see the Perl kernel in notebook

Comment: @Tarun Yeah I have updated the image as per your suggestion. Now I am able to run the notebook but Perl 6 kernel is not shown in the notebook options, though I followed the instructions as mentioned [in the page of the kernel](https://github.com/bduggan/p6-jupyter-kernel). :(

Comment: I think you missed a important step to link the kernel to Ipython. `jupyter-kernel.p6 --generate-config`

Comment: @Tarun Thank you. I got it working. Where can I read more on this `linking the kernel` ? I even wrote [a blog on running Perl 6 kernel](https://sumdoc.wordpress.com/2017/09/06/how-to-run-perl-6-notebook/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `--allow-root` in the CMD of your Dockerfile. Also you need to link the kernel with jupyter in your dockerfile

```
jupyter-kernel.p6 --generate-config
```

Once you do that you will be able to see the dockerfile. I also noticed that your images size is very huge, you should try and find a better base image for jupyter rather than the one you have.

For more details about installing kernels refer to the below link

https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-kernel.html

Comment: But I could not find about `linking kernel` in the above link.